# Remove whole group if specific string is present in column

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to keep only the `sample` that do not have "Chemo" in the `Treatment` column.

I tried with `filter`, but this don't work as it don't remove the whole group and keep group B.

```
df %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  filter(Treatment!="Chemo")
```

In:

```
> data.frame(sample=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C"), Treatment=c("Chemo","Chemo", "Chemo","Chemo","Hormon","Chemo","Hormon","Hormon"))
  sample Treatment
1      A     Chemo
2      A     Chemo
3      A     Chemo
4      A     Chemo
5      B    Hormon
6      B     Chemo
7      C    Hormon
8      C    Hormon
```

Out:

```
7      C    Hormon
8      C    Hormon
```

Maybe this?

```
df %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  filter(!any(Treatment=="Chemo"))
```